# Is there a way to have width of container bigger than the screen in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a following container which is actually bigger than the screen. But it seems like flutter doesn't allow the container width to be bigger than the screen.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Test(),
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          print("Tapped");
        },
        child: Transform.rotate(
          angle: math.pi / 4,
          child: Container(
            height: 200,
            width: 700,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to use `Transform.scale` instead but the `GestureDetector` doesn't work on the parts of container that is bigger than the screen.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Test(),
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          print("Tapped");
        },
        child: Transform.rotate(
          angle: math.pi / 4,
          child: Transform(
            transform: Matrix4.diagonal3Values(4, 1, 1),
            child: Container(
              height: 200,
              width: 300,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The container will be resized using a resize handle. I'm okay with container not having width greater than screen whilst it's not rotated but when it's rotated I want the container to have width based on resize handle which can be greater than screen. Is there any workaround for this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you require a container to be bigger than the screen?

Comment: @GrahamD The container will be resized using a resize handle. I mean I'm okay with container not having width greater than screen whilst it's not rotated. But when it's rotated to some degrees, I want the container to have width based on resize handle.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way and that is to use Stack & Positioned:

```
Stack(
    children: [
        Positioned(top: 0,
          left: 0,
          height: 200,
          width: 1000,
          child: Container(height: 200, width: 1000, color: Colors.blue),
        ),
    ],
),
```

Adjust the height and width of `Positioned` to limit how much width and height container can have.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know it's not possible to have a container bigger than the screen. You have to take into account that the idea is for the app to run on different sized screens, so I personally don't see the point in giving static values when you can use dynamic ones so it fits different devices' sizes.